# (Homework) How to change HTML background (with Perl CGI) using input and cookies from user?

Tags: html, perl, cookies, cgi

Everything works except the background color of the HTML page in the very last CGI. Can somebody help me please? I am very stuck. I don't know why the background color won't change.

**Here is the HTML:**

```
<table border="2" cellspacing="5" cellpadding="5">
<tr>
    <td align="center">Name</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="customer" size="15"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td align="center">Select Membership Type</td>
    <td>
        <input type="radio" name="membership" value="0">Life
        <input type="radio" name="membership" value="1">Annual
        <input type="radio" name="membership" value="2">Free Trial
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td align="center">Choose Background Color</td>
    <td>
        <select name="color">         
            <option value="ye">Yellow
            <option value="cy">Cyan
            <option value="ma">Magenta
            <option value="wh">White
            <option value="pi">Pink
            <option value="go">Gold
            <option value="pa">PapayaWhip
        </select>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="2" align="center"><input type="submit" value="Sign Up and Set Options"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

**CGI that saves user's cookie from HTML above:**

I am to use an array to hold the membership types, and a hash that
uses the option tag attribute values as keys for the full color names

```
my $customer = param('customer');
my $chosen_membership = param('membership');
my $color = param('color');
my @membership_type = ("Life", "Annual", "Free Trial");
my %colors = ("ye" => 'Yellow',
        "cy" => 'Cyan',
        "ma" => 'Magenta',
        "wh" => 'White',
        "pi" => 'Pink',
        "go" => 'Gold',
        "pa" => 'Papayawhip');

my $chosen_color = $colors{$color};

my $mycookie1 = cookie(-name=>'membership',
                   -value=>$membership_type[$chosen_membership],
                   -path=>'/',
                   -expires=>'+7d');

my $mycookie2 = cookie(-name=>'customer',
                   -value=>$customer,
                   -path=>'/',
                   -expires=>'+7d');

my $mycookie3 = cookie(-name=>"color",
                   -value=>$chosen_color,
                   -path=>'/',
                   -expires=>'+7d');                    

print header(-cookie => [$mycookie1, $mycookie2, $mycookie3]);
print start_html ( -title => 'Assignment 7');
print "Thank you. Your data has been recorded</br>";
print "<a href='test3.cgi'>See member page</a>";
print end_html;
```

**Reading the cookie** and using the selected color from the HTML as the background color for the page

```
my $membership_name = cookie("membership");
my $customer_name = cookie("customer");
my $color_name = cookie("color");

print header, start_html;
#what the hell, how to change background color??

<body bgcolor="$color_name">;
print "<h2>Welcome back, $membership_name Member $customer_name.</h2>";
print "<h4>Site rather poor, huh? Sorry. We are working on it.</h4>";
print end_html;
```

Comment: I forgot to add some information. I am very stuck. Everything is working but the background color will not change.

Comment: so what have you tried to do so far? what is the result of what you've tried and what would you expect to happen?

Comment: @JonTaylor The membership array and the customer name are being saved successfully. The background color is not saving. I used `my $chosen_color = $colors{$color};` to save the chosen color and 

`my $mycookie3 = cookie(-name=>"color",
                   -value=>$chosen_color,` to save that variable in the cookie

Comment: Have you used your browser's developer tools to look at the cookies? What is being set? What is the bgcolor attribute being set to on your web page?

Comment: @DaveCross the bgcolor attribute is taken from `<body bgcolor="$color_name">;`. That's where the color cookie is being saved

Comment: Sorry, I was unclear. Yes, I can see the code. I was asking what you actually see there when you view the HTML source code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<body bgcolor="$color_name">;
```

You're missing a `print` and some quotes here. I'm surprised this runs at all.

What you probably mean is:

```
print "<body bgcolor='$color_name'>";
```

Comment: I overlooked that part. Thank you so much for helping